# I am writing a DXL script to print a modulename with path using a function . I need to remove if the directory has remote in that path

Tags: regex, path, ibm-doors

Below module is forming a directory from a path

**`Checkmodules("Cus", "projectname".cfg", ".*(Cus|Cer Requirements|Cer Speci|ASM|/ASM24e|Specs).*");`**

The above line forms below folder directory, so I need to modify it when the directory has `remote` in the path its should be removed entire directory.

Output path

```
Cus/spec/cer/
cus/val_remote/value - this also needs to be removed
Cus/sys/remote   ---- to be removed entire path
```

Comment: where is the problem with the negative criteria? Your third parameter contains the positive criteria. So, in your existing code there will be a line like `if (reParamThree fullName currentModule) {put skCandidates, currentModule, currrentModule}`. Just add a fourth parameter and augment the code with `if (reParamThree fullName currentModule && !reParamFour fullName currentModule) {put skCandidates, currentModule, currentModule}` and your calling line would be `Checkmodules("Cus", "projectname".cfg", ".*(Cus|Cer Requirements|Cer Speci|ASM|/ASM24e|Specs).*", "remote")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a replace (to an empty string) with the following regex combined with the flag `g` (global=all occurrences) and `m` (multiline)

```
^.*remote.*$
```

In JavaScript this would be :

```
outputPath.replace(/^.*remote.*$/gm, '')
```

Comment: Hello @wiktor 
is it possible to add in the below line to ignore it. this expression ignore the conformity but not the entire path.
Cus|Cer Requirements|Cer Specification|02 - Regulatory|\\*\\remote.\|

Comment: @premranjith: usually, you would solve this with an additonal pattern, one for the positive criteria (Cus, Cer requirements etc) and one for negative criteria. This would result in a pseudo code like 'grep all modules which match to the positive criteria to an array and afterwards remove all elements from this array which match to the negative criteria'

Comment: @mike can you help me with it?